# Retrieve UserID to Change a users Password

Tags: desire2learn

I am working on a process to change a users password in D2L via the API.  I'm using PHP.

I need to push a users password change to D2L from another system.  Example when the user changes their password in our Portal, I want to make a call to update the password in D2L via the API.  In looking over the docs and I need the users "UserID" to make the PUT call as such:

```
PUT system/d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/UserID/password
{"Password": "HelloWorld5"}
```

How to I obtain this UserID?  I can do a WhoAmI call but that is only valid for the logged in user.  I do not see an api that I can call up the users account by UserName and obtain their UserID.

- Keep in mind the user will not be logging into D2L during this password change and the portal does not have the UserID stored in it.  So I need to be able to obtain the userid and then make the password change call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the user ID for a user based on their username, use the following call:

[/d2l/api/lp/{VERSION}/users/](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-users-)

It can take the username as an argument (userName) otherwise it will return a complete (but paged) list of users. Note that this call requires sufficient (administrator/etc. privileges.)

Comment: Note that the 'users' API call can indeed look up a user record based on `OrgDefinedId` or by `UserName`; however, if you use the call that way, then it seeks for exact matches only (so you must provide the preciser UserName or OrgDefinedId). Note also that if you seek to find a user by OrgDefinedId, the returned structure is an array of user records (because OrgDefinedId is not necessarily a unique property for some organizations); if you seek to find a user by UserName, the returned structure (if matched) will be a single UserData structure.

Comment: Accessing a users info with GET system/d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/<<user>> <-I can only get the D2L UserID to work here to pull back user info.  If I try a unique UserName or OrgDefinedID then a 404 error comes back.  EXAMPLE:  A user in our system has a UserID of 3900.  I can pull the data and update the password using the UserID, but if I try the other two 404 error occurs.
"UserId": 3900,
    "UserName": "hefnerj",
    "OrgDefinedId": "910292538"

Comment: To use the userName as a parameter to that call, do a GET to `/d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/?userName=<foo>` (query parameters go after the route, starting with a ?, in key=value pairs separated by ampersands.)